# MySQL Workbench not allowing me to run query

Tags: mysql, sql, database, mysql-workbench

So I installed mysql and mysql workbench now my goal is to run 20 different queries on the schema and database I installed onto it. to install the schema and database I used File => Open Sql Script and then selected the schema then the database to install them. However I seem to have a issue where the lightning bolt icon you use to run scripts isn't high lighted and it's not allowing me to run anything and I don't know why.
[image]

[image]

Comment: you didn't run the script click on the lighning strike button

Comment: Is says "unconnected". You need to define a connection and connect to the MySQL instance first.

Comment: @nbk that's the problem...it's not allowing me to click the lightning strike button

Comment: @jurez can you explain to me how to do that?

Comment: @FallenDionysus Use the menu or read the manual.

Comment: @jurez I've been reading the manual and it's not working, that's the problem

Comment: @FallenDionysus Which step of the manual is not working? https://dev.mysql.com/doc/workbench/en/wb-getting-started-tutorial-create-connection.html

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/230722/discussion-between-fallen-dionysus-and-jurez).

Comment: @jurez I added a new screenshot, i try to create a connection and when I press "test connection" I get unable to connect to localhost error

Comment: then the server is not running.